# Google Sheets / Clear Format in script moving row to other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet with two tabs. I have been using a script that sends a row from TESTSHEET1 to TESTSHEET2 once I check off a box. When it moves over it brings with it multiple conditional formatting rules into TESTSHEET2, to the point where I have to clear all formatting and then re-apply what I need. I have tried different things I've seen online but nothing seems to work. I'd like to add to this script as opposed to a new one because it has worked great for me all this time! Please help. This is the code I have been using

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "TESTSHEET1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TESTSHEET2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

I'm not too great with code so I don't know how to add to this.
And here is a link of a sample sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUzOYdtLzr_98oFHJ8zzq9MTby6LDadAzn6hHNIs9sk/edit?usp=sharing

Help!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Conditional');
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setValues(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues());
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't seem to do anything. In case I didn't do a good job explaining, I need anything checked true in column A to move to the other sheet without conditional formatting and it needs to happen before it moves to TESTSHEET2 so the conditional formatting doesn't follow it.

Comment: Unless I used it wrong please let me know. I just copied and pasted replacing the one I had

Comment: Okay try it again.  It's working now.  I tested it.  You probably need to change the sheet names.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. It's perfect

Comment: I do have another question actually. It works exactly how I need it too so this is kind of unnecessary but if it's an easy edit, is there a way to add the rows in "Sheet2" at the very top instead of the bottom?